# Compare Enum Values

Tags: enums, ada

I want to loop over an array and check, whether the current array index is a value of an enumeration. The array as well as the enumeration are defined as the following:

```ada
type Option is (None, A, B, C, D);
type Votes is array(Option) of Natural;

Zero_Option_Distribution: constant Votes := (others => 0);
Votes_Distribution: Votes := Zero_Option_Distribution;
```

The Loop looks like this:

```ada
for I in Voting_System.Votes_Distribution'Range loop
   -- this is where I would like to check whether I is a representation of either of the enum values
end loop;
```

I already tried everything that came to my mind, like

```ada
if I = Voting_System.Option(None) then -- ...
```

and

```ada
if I'Val("None") then -- ...
```

and some more versions where each of them didn't work.

I really don't have any more ideas to achieve this.

Comment: Well the type of `I` is the index type of `Votes_Distribution`, which is `Party` not `Option`. So what you're doing doesn't seem to make sense. If `Party` was declared somewhere else as a subtype of `Option` which includes `None` then `if I = None` should work (assuming you made the relevant  declarations visible).

Comment: Updating your question with a definition of Party might give some clarity to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare values of objects of enumeration types just like objects of any other type, using `=`:

```ada
if I = None then
   ...
end if;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found the solution literally 20 minutes after asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

> ```ada
> -- this is where I would like to check whether I is a representation of either of the enum values
> ```

Based on this line in your question, I assume `Party` is an Integer subtype or something? You should be able to just use something like this:

```ada
-- (Checks if I is 0)
if (Integer(I) = Voting_System.Option'Pos(Voting_System.Option.None)) then
-- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If *Party* is a distinct type, in accordance with ARM95 3.5.1 §7 and ARM95 Annex K §175 you may try something like this:

```
  for I in Votes_Distribution'Range loop
     case Party'Pos (I) is
     when Option'Pos (None) => Put_Line (I'Img & " is for «None»");
     when Option'Pos (A)    => Put_Line (I'Img & " is for «A»");
     when Option'Pos (B)    => Put_Line (I'Img & " is for «B»");
     when Option'Pos (C)    => Put_Line (I'Img & " is for «C»");
     when Option'Pos (D)    => Put_Line (I'Img & " is for «D»");
     when others            => Put_Line ("I not in Option");
     end case;
  end loop;
```

Need **others** in all cases because we moved to work with type *Universal_Integer*.